# Javascript Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variable' before initialization at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, html

I am hoping that someone can help me here.  I am getting an error when trying to upload files. On the click event it's throwing an error and not sure why it is not initializing the  fileupload. Here is my code:

```
    const btnUpload = document.getElementById('btnUpload');
    const formSubmit = document.getElementById('formSubmit');
    btnUpload.addEventListener('click', async function(event) {
        if (!formSubmit.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
        } else {
            showSpinner1();

            let createId = reqCreate.data.id;

            // Upload Bulk Files
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", fileupload.files[0]);

            let newfile = formData.get('file', fileupload.files[0]);
            console.log(newfile.name); //filename
            console.log(newfile.size); //filesize

            for (var fileUpload of fileupload.files) {

                // Retrieve Document Placeholder
                let reqDocument;
                await axios.get(`api/${createId}/documents`, {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        reqDocument = response;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

                console.log(reqDocument);

                // Get Media Url
                let documentId = reqDocument.data[0].id;
                console.log(documentId);

                const mediaData = {
                    "file": {
                        "contentType": "application/pdf",
                        "name": "test.pdf",
                        "size": 10000
                    },
                    "title": companyName.value + '_' + borrFirstName.value + borrLastName.value + '_' + fileUpload.name,
                }

                let reqMedia;
                await axios.post(`api/${createId}/attachmentUploadUrl`, mediaData, {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        reqMedia = response;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

                console.log(reqMedia.data.uploadUrl);


                // Get Media URL for Cover Letter
                let mediaString = reqMedia.data.uploadUrl;

                let reqFile;
                await axios.put(mediaString, fileUpload, {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": 'application/pdf',
                            "Authorization": reqMedia.data.authorizationHeader
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        reqFile = response;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

                console.log(reqFile.data.id);


                // Upload Attachments to Document Placeholder
                let fileNumber = reqMedia.data.attachmentId;

                let fileData = [{
                    "entityId": fileNumber,
                    "entityType": "attachment"
                }];

                let reqAttach;
                await axios.patch(`api/${createId}/documents/${documentId}/attachments?action=add`, fileData, {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        reqAttach = response;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

                console.log(reqAttach);
            }
            hideSpinner1();

            confirm.innerHTML = '<font size = "6">Success!!</font>' + ' ' + 'The files have been uploaded!! You are all done now!!';
            setInterval(clearLabel, 5000);
        }
        formSubmit.classList.add('was-validated');

        if (formSubmit.checkValidity() === true) {
            formSubmit.classList.remove('was-validated');
            clearForm()
        }

    }, false)
};
```

Html:

```
<div class="p-2 bd-highlight justify-content-center">
            <h5 class="text-center">Step 2: Upload Files to Encompass Loan Record</h5>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header text-center">
                    <h2>Upload Files</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body card_body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="upload-container">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" multiple required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label id="confirm" style="color: rgb(16, 139, 47);font-weight: bold;"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="button" style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg button" id="btnUpload" name="btnUpload">Upload Documents</button>
                    <div class="loader1">
                        <div class="loading1"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

And here is the error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fileupload' before initialization at HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: Have you added the script tag at the end of body tag?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: Add your html in the question.

Comment: Just added it to the original question.

Comment: In the starting line of `btnUpload event listener`, where is your formSubmit variable? You have initialize it before you can use it.

Comment: Yes, just updated the code above again.  I have initialized it already in my code before the btnUpload event listener.

Comment: In the code above where you add `var formData=new FormData()`, below that you've added `fileupload.files[0]`, where is fileupload

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  So, what are you saying, that I should move this out of the event listener?  Should I initialize fileupload outside of the event listener?

Comment: Yes fileUpload should be initialized like you've initialized btnUpload and formSubmit, outside the eventListener's scope

Comment: Ok, I added it and still getting the same error.

Comment: What is `reqCreate`?

Comment: I got it.  There was a caching issue with host.  I figured it out.  It's working now.  Thanks for your help @Inder